# Need help identifying component

Tags: diodes, components, identification

can you help me identify these components?

I know this is a normal diode:
[image: normal diode]

But what is this: (labelled DW1 on the board - is it a zener?)
[image: gray black diode]

And this? (labelled V6 on the board - zeners also look like this)
[image: Glass diode]

**UPDATE**

Came out of a chicago electric flux wire welder. Feed motor control board.
Made in **china** most likely as it is a harbor freight product. Not known to have any issues.

Pictures of the board front and back below, annotated.

Brown wires - power

Green wires - torch switch

Red/Black wires - motor

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

M - motor

P - power

SW - switch

Comment: What's the marking on DW1?

Comment: more context might be helpful – though it's very nice to see these components in isolation, a kind of an "environment" for DW1 might help classifying it.

Comment: what purpose does this board serve? That might give interesting hints!

Comment: Get out your meter and put it in diode mode and find the voltage.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did the board come from? I mean what nationality. That can change the naming conventions a lot.

Comment: Made in China most likely.

Comment: @laptop2d I'm an amateur but I figure it's important whether it's a zener or a regular diode. It could be for regulating voltage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's a motor speed control for a wire welder.

Comment: @winny I don't have the board with me but I don't recall the markings being useful. Or rather ... I mean it was a couple of letters (one of them micro (u) I think?). Couldn't see them too well.

Comment: It's all very weird, but if I had to guess from that layout, without knowing what the other parts are, the DW one is a zener. If you draw out a proper schematic with what you can identify so far, we might be able to improve our guesses...

Comment: all those parts should be marked with numbers identifying what type they are.  the numbers may be facing the board so some disassembly may be required.

Answer (score 1):

## V6 [image: diode]

This is just a glass housing. It's (was, in pre-SMD times) pretty common for diodes. The fact that it's labeled "V" is a bit confusing.

I've got three possible explanation:

- **V**aricap: a diode used in non-conducting bias. The bias voltage determines the capacity of the isolating zone in the diode
- **V**oltage Reference: A Zener used as voltage reference

*personally*, I tend towards the second. But: with more info on the purpose, we might say more.

But @Trevor made an important point: older techs tend to misname "diodes" with "varistor". My guess is that this is what happened here, since all your diodes are labeled V. So, V6 is some small-signal diode in a glass package. That's all we can possibly say about it. There's  thousands of different diode types that were sold in glass packages.

Even the one three-pinned device V2 and V5 are labeled V – although every bet would be they're transistors. I'm frankly  beginning to think the names on your board don't actually correlate with the type of component...

## DW1 [image: DW1]

The marking on the board indicate it's a polarized component. The D might be a good indication it's also a diode.

Given there's a weak correlation between device type and letter used, it's probably just some specific diode. Again, without your own measurements, we can't guess much.

Comment: Varistor is also a commonly used, or rather **misused** term for a diode too.

Comment: @Trevor yeah, but I know varistors only as devices in packages that look like they can get rid of a lot more excess heat than this glass packages

Comment: agreed, hence the "misused" statement. I have heard a lot of older technicians call standard diodes varistors over the years though.

Comment: @Trevor oh, I didn't know that misnomer! Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @Trevor oh I see OPs photos now, yea, probably just simple diodes mislabeled with V like varistor, then.

Comment: V is standard for diodes in some half-obscure CAD programs, so it could be a regular diode. Absence of any D nominators (except DW) adds to this theory.

Comment: @winny what exactly are V2 and V5, if not transistors? I think the naming is total bonkers.

Comment: CADSTAR uses V for all semiconductors in some library configurations. Both diodes and transistors. We do at work and last place had modified the library to chance it to D and T respectively, from all V.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "your own measurements" Can the type of diode be measured with a multimeter?

Comment: @Shorin, for a fuller picture, you'll have to do some careful U/I curves, after removing the diode from the circuit. You'll have to remove it in any case (there's always resistors in parallel), but your multimeter might at least give you the forward voltage!

Comment: Is anyone more certain of what DW1 Is? I should close this question soon